# JS validation function skips over fields and starts in the middle

Tags: javascript, lotus-domino

This is a piece of a much longer (25 or more) function but it gives you an idea of what is happening. It seems straight forward, start at the first field, validate it, if it fails, pop an alert and position the cursor in the field.

Unfortunately what is happening is that it is skipping over the first dozen or so fields and starting with the DateDue field and working backwards from there. It also does not pop the alert message.

The code is in the JSHeader and called from the Submit button.

Any thoughts on what I am doing wrong?

```
function validate(){
var validatemsg;
var validateflag;
validateflag = 'false';

 if(document.forms[0].LocationName.value == ''){
 validatemsg='LOCATION NAME FIELD ERROR: Location Name is required to successfully process your request.';
 validateflag='true';
 document.forms[0].LocationName.focus()
 }
 if(document.forms[0].LocPhone.value == '') {
 validatemsg='LOCATION PHONE FIELD ERROR: Location Phone is required to successfully process your request.';
 validateflag='true';
 document.forms[0].LocPhone.focus()
 }
 if(document.forms[0].LocFax.value == '') {
 validatemsg='LOCATION FAX FIELD ERROR: Location Fax is required to successfully process your     request.';
 validateflag='true';
 document.forms[0].LocFax.focus()
 }
```

another dozen or so fields set up exactly the same way and then

```
 if(document.forms[0].DateDue.value == '') {
  validatemsg='DATE DUE FIELD ERROR: Date Due is required to successfully process your request.';
  validateflag='true';
  document.forms[0].DateDue.focus()
 }
  if(document.forms[0].DateDue.value.length != 10) {
  validatemsg='DATE DUE FIELD ERROR: Date Due should be in mm/dd/yyyy format.';
  validateflag='true';
  document.forms[0].DateDue.focus()
  }

  if(document.forms[0].AgreeType.value == '') {
  validatemsg='AGREEMENT TYPE FIELD ERROR: AgreementType is required to successfully process your request.';
  validateflag='true';
  document.forms[0].AgreeType.focus()
  }

 if(validateflag == 'true'){
 alert(validatemsg);
 }
 if(validateflag == 'false'){
 document.forms[0].submit()
 }
 }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to separate things a little. As you want to stop on the first validation fail, you have to return out of the `validate()` function.

Have a look below (I've added comments), add `return` to each of your if checks

```
// Declare these outside the function
var validatemsg;
var validateflag = false; /* don't use a string */

function validate(){
    if (document.forms[0].LocationName.value == ''){
        validatemsg = 'LOCATION NAME FIELD ERROR: Location Name is required to successfully process your request.';
        validateflag = true;
        document.forms[0].LocationName.focus();
        return; /* <-- Important, get out of the validator */
    }
    /*  add rest of if blocks from here down */
}

if (validateflag){
    alert(validatemsg);
}
if (!validateflag){
    document.forms[0].submit()
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick answer. 30+ years of writing software and I missed the obvious. I feel so stupid now.